# How can I use "do while" command here?

Tags: java

I am learning java, here's my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("Enter Password");
        String value = input.nextLine();


        if(value.equals("mycat")){
            System.out.println("Password Accepted!");
            System.out.println("My Personal Number is: ");
            System.out.println("blahblah");
        }
        else 
            System.out.println("Incorrect Password!");


        }


    }
```

I want to keep saying incorrect password and allow to enter another rather than stopping. Basically I want looping but when ever I do this, I don't get results that I want.

Comment: *"but when ever I do this, I don't get results that I want."* Please post these attempts.

Answer (score 3):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

do
{
    System.out.println("Enter Password");
    String value = input.nextLine();

    if(value.equals("mycat")){
        System.out.println("Password Accepted!");
        System.out.println("My Personal Number is: ");
        System.out.println("blahblah");
    }
    else 
        System.out.println("Incorrect Password!");
} while(!value.equals("mycat"))

input.close();
```

Enclose code within Try-Catch block.

Comment: You need a break or something in your if statement. This will run as long as the password is mycat...

Comment: Hey Rajesh, Thanks for your help. I removed "!" exclamation sign from:
while(!value.equals("mycat"))
and looping stopped. This is what I was missing. Can you explain why does "!" makes this difference? And what is the work of "input.close();". I deleted that and it made no changes
Also what do you mean by enclosing within Try-Catch block? Sorry I am new to it.

Comment: Ok I understood one thing that why you used "!". It actually means keep looping while condition is not true.

Comment: [Java Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String value;
    System.out.println("Enter Password");
    value = input.nextLine();
    while(!value.equals("mycat")) {
       System.out.println("Incorrect Password!");
       System.out.println("Enter Password");
       value = input.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("Password accepted"); // if you are here then the password is good
}
```

Comment: I edit my code to show when you need to print it : if you are in the loop so the password is wrong and then if you are after the loop, the password is good.

Comment: Thank you so much. So it could be done without "do".

Comment: Yes just put the "do" before the first System.out.println and it's done.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a *function* to deal with the password acquisition:

```
String getPassword(/*you might need to pass input as a parameter*/)
{
    while (true){ /*an infinite loop*/
        String value = input.nextLine();
        if (value.equals("mycat")){
            return value;
        }
        System.out.println("Incorrect Password!");
    }
}
```

This will help you scale your program with minimal changes to the caller of `getPassword`:

1. Move away from hardcoding `"mycat"`
2. Use a special object designed for modelling passwords. `String` is insecure since the data are in a contiguous block.
3. Introduce a maximum number of trials, with possible delay loops.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different while loops in Java.

```
do {
    //Code here
} while (/*Condition here */)
```

and

```
while (/*Condition here */) {
    //Code here
}
```

The first one tests for condition after the code in the brackets is executed, the second one does the test before.
Which means with `do { } while()` you run the code inside once before you check the condition for the first time, which is what you want.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String value;

    do{
        System.out.println("Enter Password");
        value = input.nextLine();

        if(value.equals("mycat")){
            System.out.println("Password Accepted!");
            System.out.println("My Personal Number is: ");
            System.out.println("blahblah");
        }
        else 
            System.out.println("Incorrect Password!");

    } while (!value.equals("mycat"))

}
```

Something like this could be what you want

Comment: Yep thats it. Thanks for your help!